# How to fix z-index for img in parent div

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="caller shadow-circle-lg"><img src="public/img/example-photo.png"></div>
```

And CSS:

```
.shadow-circle-lg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    border: 8px solid white;
}

div.caller {
        z-index: 200;
}

.caller > img {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Why is the IMG element still rendering over the div border, even though it has a lower z-index (yes, I have checked the DOM in Chrome).

Also, is there any way I can force the div border radius to crop the image?

Please note, I don't want to apply any classes to the IMG itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can force the border radius to crop by setting `overflow: hidden;` on your parent element (in `.shadow-circle-lg`)

It is important to note that `z-index` property ONLY works on positioned elements (like `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. Try adding this property to the `<div>` and `<img>` element(s).

Final CSS markup:

```
.shadow-circle-lg {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33), inset 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
    border: 8px solid white;
    overflow: hidden; /* "crop" by hiding overflow content */
}

div.caller {
    z-index: 200;
    position: relative; /* position so z-index is recognized */
}

.caller > img {
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative; /* position so z-index is recognized */
}
```